# Function header that can contain 0 or more assignments

Tags: python, function, parameters, header

I want to create a function header that can have 0 or more assignments:
for example:

```
function(1, 2, 3)
returns: [1, 2, 3]

function(4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
returns:[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

function(1, 2)
returns: [1,2]
```

It needs to be able to take as many assignments as the user inputs, can anyone help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> def foo(*args):
...    return list(args)
... 
>>> foo(1, 2, 3)
[1, 2, 3]
```